# Sending a POST query in JSON using JQuery and Django

Tags: jquery, json, django

I'm very confused about the urls when it comes to sending/receiving data.

The snippet I'm trying in my views is very simple:

```
class EditGetInfo(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            response_data = {}
            response_data['test'] = 'Test message'
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

In my urls I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^edit/getInfo$', EditGetInfo.as_view()),
    url(r'^edit/', Edit.as_view()),
    url(r'^$', Home.as_view()),
]
```

My goal is to send the request to website.com/edit/getInfo.

And I try to do it as (this is loaded when I open website.com/edit):

```
$.post("edit/getInfo",function(data) {
        alert(data);
});
```

Comment: so what error are you getting

Comment: Your ajax should probably be posting to an absolute path: `$.post("/edit/getInfo"...)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are facing issue with urls. so your post request is going in Edit view instead of EditGetInfo.
If this is the case then you have issue with urls.
change following url

```
url(r'^edit/getInfo$', EditGetInfo.as_view()),
```

with

```
url(r'^edit/getInfo/$', EditGetInfo.as_view()),
```